# Phonegap using Iphone camera

Tags: javascript, iphone, cordova

Hi i am developing Phonegap application using html and javascript. But i'am developing on windows. Is it possible to use iphone camera in phonegap without mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

100% brother why not, I am also working on windows for iPhone and Android using Phonegap. It will work and here is the full tutorial for your help

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera

Comment: Looked to your link. I dont have The Command-line Interface. Must i install Command-line Interface first to add camera plugin?

Comment: no need to use command line, just call the function after attach its plugin in config.xml ...... i am updating my answer also just check once again link

Comment: Is it enough only adding plugin to config.xml?